# Navigate to page and highlight menu item when navigating from home page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-template

I'm currently creating a app with Ionic 2+ and Angular 2. It is currently working great but i have some trouble with navigating and highlighting menu items.
I have a contact button on the homepage of my app (home.html and home.ts)

[image: Contact button on homepage]

I can navigate to the correct page using:

```
this.navCtrl.root(ContactPage)
```

but the page **isn't** highlighted in the menu like this (when i navigate from the sidemenu):

[image: Side menu highlighted]

I have a activePage param in my app.component.ts where the active page is set when i click on a sidemenu item. This param is checked when loading in the menu by loading in a style when its true:

```
isActive(page: PageInterface){
    if(this.activePage == page)
    {
      return true
    }
}
```

I don't know how i can set this parameter in app.component.ts from home.ts when i click the button on my homepage.

Does anyone have a tip or trick to get me in the right direction.

More code:

Example of how i generate the menu item:

```
<ion-item [class.activeItem]="isActive(p)" no-lines *ngFor="let p of MiscPages" (click)="openPage(p)">
```

app.component.ts structure of the pages list:

```
this.MiscPages = [
  { title: 'MENU.INFO_BTN', name: 'Information', component: InformationPage, icon: 'ios-information-circle' },
  { title: 'MENU.CONTACT_BTN', name: 'Contact', component: ContactPage, icon: 'ios-paper-plane' },
  { title: 'MENU.SETTINGS_BTN', name: 'Settings', component: SettingsPage, icon: 'ios-settings' }
]
```

Comment: use a shared service to keep track of which page is currently active.

Comment: So instead of having a local variable in app.component i create a service that contains this variable but is available for the complete app (where i import)?

Comment: Yes right. Create a service with get() and set() methods. Let me post it as an answer.

Comment: I tried to do that but the side menu didn't update. I will wait for your answer.

Comment: does answer make sense?

Comment: The answer does make perfect sense! I'm going to try it!

Comment: do tell if there are any issues.

Comment: try `return page == this.activePage` instead of the `if` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shared service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private currentPage: string;
  constructor() { }

  getData() {
    return this.currentPage;
  }

  setData(page) {
    this.currentPage = page;
  }
}
```

Import the service in your app module like this:

```
import { SharedService } from './shared/shared.service'; //Change the path as per your file location
```

add the service to providers array like this:

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [],
      providers: [SharedService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

Inject this service in your components and use the get() and set() methods to save and retrieve currently active page:

```
this.SharedService.setData('Current Active Page'); // To save current page
this.SharedService.getData('Current Active Page'); // To get current page
```

you can change the css based on the response you get from getData() method. I hope this makes sense.